# Crash.txt generated while sending mail from xampp php & Socket Error # 11001

Tags: php, delphi, email, xampp

following file generated while trying to send email

```
date/time         : 2015-05-15, 15:00:18, 188ms
computer name     : GS-1459
user name         : GS-1076
registered owner  : gslab / Hewlett-Packard Company
operating system  : Windows 7 x64 Service Pack 1 build 7601
system language   : English
system up time    : 6 hours 11 minutes
program up time   : 4 seconds
processors        : 4x Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3470 CPU @ 3.20GHz
physical memory   : 5446/8080 MB (free/total)
free disk space   : (C:) 306.09 GB
display mode      : 1600x900, 32 bit
process id        : $a08
allocated memory  : 23.68 MB
command line      : "C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe" -t
executable        : sendmail.exe
exec. date/time   : 2011-06-18 01:10
compiled with     : Delphi 2006/07
madExcept version : 3.0l
callstack crc     : $fecf9b34, $3d6bf7f9, $3d6bf7f9
exception number  : 1
exception class   : EIdSMTPReplyError
exception message : <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbtfv 5hD_HQmfrnpudHeE2tDRSqLsZ26cC_H0zkQFvqKJAH4XxYfTLfcekb9MnJ8P4ydol7ZBxK S95_ifKnpJxC2KCiqfXi43DGPS34fKAshagLVJFe_mH9gxPc4ypWJGwCwm0N9tluAwKe5L jnLxgdTcGjDBkWVax6N3xQ5uCQ_mdixIntMvJyRVWIDNbjzLIgJRo8KQ-BB1FgJpboh9qO lX8vUeVA9B4q0hkRaScUklGn3VfI> Please log in via your web browser and then try again. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 ki3sm1250206pdb.74 - gsmtp.

main thread ($1644):
0045918a +003e sendmail.exe IdReplySMTP     501   +1 TIdReplySMTP.RaiseReplyError
0043ff28 +0008 sendmail.exe IdTCPConnection 576   +0 TIdTCPConnection.RaiseExceptionForLastCmdResult
004402f4 +003c sendmail.exe IdTCPConnection 751  +10 TIdTCPConnection.CheckResponse
0043feba +002a sendmail.exe IdTCPConnection 565   +2 TIdTCPConnection.GetResponse
0043ff87 +005b sendmail.exe IdTCPConnection 585   +4 TIdTCPConnection.SendCmd
0044020e +0056 sendmail.exe IdTCPConnection 723   +4 TIdTCPConnection.SendCmd
0045aa16 +0192 sendmail.exe IdSMTP          341  +40 TIdSMTP.Authenticate
004b5f81 +10cd sendmail.exe sendmail        822 +340 initialization
76853368 +0010 kernel32.dll                          BaseThreadInitThunk

thread $f54:
77ba1f3b +0b ntdll.dll     NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory
76853368 +10 kernel32.dll  BaseThreadInitThunk

thread $16e8:
77ba0152 +0e ntdll.dll     NtWaitForMultipleObjects
76853368 +10 kernel32.dll  BaseThreadInitThunk

stack dump:
0018fccc  8f 91 45 00 de fa ed 0e - 01 00 00 00 07 00 00 00  ..E.............
0018fcdc  e0 fc 18 00 8f 91 45 00 - 18 cb e3 01 10 1e e5 01  ......E.........
0018fcec  00 00 00 00 16 02 00 00 - 10 fd 18 00 fc fc 18 00  ................
0018fcfc  50 fd 18 00 c8 4b 40 00 - 10 fd 18 00 34 a5 45 00  P....K@.....4.E.
0018fd0c  00 00 00 00 2c fd 18 00 - 2b ff 43 00 f7 02 44 00  ....,...+.C...D.
0018fd1c  00 00 00 00 98 fd 18 00 - 98 fd 18 00 40 40 df 01  ............@@..
0018fd2c  44 fd 18 00 bd fe 43 00 - 00 00 00 00 94 34 46 00  D.....C......4F.
0018fd3c  00 00 00 00 34 a5 45 00 - 70 fd 18 00 8a ff 43 00  ....4.E.p.....C.
0018fd4c  00 00 00 00 80 fd 18 00 - c8 4b 40 00 70 fd 18 00  .........K@.p...
0018fd5c  00 00 00 00 eb 00 00 00 - 34 a5 45 00 98 fd 18 00  ........4.E.....
0018fd6c  00 00 00 00 a0 fd 18 00 - 14 02 44 00 00 00 00 00  ..........D.....
0018fd7c  00 00 00 00 ac fd 18 00 - c8 4b 40 00 a0 fd 18 00  .........K@.....
0018fd8c  14 3f 41 00 00 00 00 00 - 34 a5 45 00 eb 00 18 00  .?A.....4.E.....
0018fd9c  00 00 00 00 e8 fd 18 00 - 1b aa 45 00 00 00 00 00  ..........E.....
0018fdac  b8 fd 18 00 c8 4b 40 00 - e8 fd 18 00 f0 fd 18 00  .....K@.........
0018fdbc  c8 4b 40 00 e8 fd 18 00 - ff 00 00 00 48 67 dd 01  .K@.........Hg..
0018fdcc  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - eb 00 4e 01 00 00 00 00  ..........N.....
0018fddc  50 6a e2 01 00 00 00 00 - 40 40 df 01 88 ff 18 00  Pj......@@......
0018fdec  87 5f 4b 00 fc fd 18 00 - c8 4b 40 00 88 ff 18 00  ._K......K@.....
0018fdfc  08 fe 18 00 c8 4b 40 00 - 88 ff 18 00 14 fe 18 00  .....K@.........

disassembling:
[...]
00459177       call    -$1f480 ($439cfc)      ; IdReply.TIdReply.GetNumericCode
0045917c       mov     ecx, eax
0045917e       mov     dl, 1
00459180       mov     eax, [$458844]
00459185       call    +$182 ($45930c)        ; IdReplySMTP.EIdSMTPReplyError.CreateError
0045918a     > call    -$544a3 ($404cec)      ; System.@RaiseExcept
0045918f 502   xor     eax, eax
00459191       pop     edx
00459192       pop     ecx
00459193       pop     ecx
00459194       mov     fs:[eax], edx
[...]
```

Replicacted my settings from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost) and off cource email is not getting sent..

error in error.log file

```
15-05-15 15:00:37 : <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbtvR<EOL>rdTJ74fC6pXNYQTMRn-CBnehS3CfRP1JYu26NS6NkTE8FKcDWCRnPore2gBPfpg44XWZmn<EOL>IuVn7TWbXhdKJVLZnzV_br0vy4Towe2tnXvmApW3koIudeaPxX2yGWGJu1kvmHHoduM17L<EOL>QzUxjQqe5cDs9Fok5Hj4qcccc4B2GFFSbFC-XdquKuVV0jk_oLhWKaecLU3W0nAX4eVEcY<EOL>8fbG7yPSfLiyYRtd3c8NfRImaKGI> Please log in via your web browser and<EOL>then try again.<EOL>Learn more at<EOL>https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 pd10sm1254397pdb.66 - gsmtp<EOL>
```

this error when using gmail id

and while using other domain

```
15-05-15 14:31:52 : Socket Error # 11001<EOL>Host not found.
```

Comment: "Please log in via your web browser and then try again. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 ki3sm1250206pdb.74 - gsmtp." - Are you sure you're using the right remote address and the right credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution here on this [link](http://blog.techwheels.net/send-email-from-localhost-wamp-server-using-sendmail/) it works

This solution requires sendmail.exe (a Command Line Interface (CLI) executable which accepts email from PHP, connects to an SMTP server and sends email). You will not require to use it by command, don’t bother about it :-) Download the [sendmail.zip](http://www.glob.com.au/sendmail/sendmail.zip) and follow these steps:

```
Create a folder named “sendmail” in “C:\wamp\”.
Extract these 4 files in “sendmail” folder: “sendmail.exe”, “libeay32.dll”, “ssleay32.dll” and “sendmail.ini”.
Open the “sendmail.ini” file and configure it as following
    smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
    smtp_port=465
    smtp_ssl=ssl
    default_domain=localhost
    error_logfile=error.log
    debug_logfile=debug.log
    auth_username=[your_gmail_account_username]@gmail.com
    auth_password=[your_gmail_account_password]
    pop3_server=
    pop3_username=
    pop3_password=
    force_sender=
    force_recipient=
    hostname=localhost
```

You do not need to specify any value for these properties: `pop3_server`, `pop3_username`, `pop3_password`, `force_sender`, `force_recipient`. The `error_logfile` and `debug_logfile` settings should be kept blank if you have already sent successful email(s) otherwise size of this file will keep increasing. Enable these log file settings if you don’t get able to send email using sendmail.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to read the [error message](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754)?

- E-mail account may have 2-factor auth enabled. You need to setup "application specific" password.
- Google may ban you - recognized as "spam". You have to log in via browser and enter captcha.